# How to optimize a SQL query using multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL query here that grabs the 5 latest news posts. I want to make it so it also grabs the total likes and total news comments in the same query. But the query I made seems to be a little slow when working with large amounts of data so I am trying to see if I can find a better solution. Here it is below:

```
SELECT *, 
`id` as `newscode`, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE `type`="newspost" AND `code`=`newscode`) as `total_likes`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `news_comments` WHERE `post_id`=`newscode`) as `total_comments`
FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Here is a SQLFiddle as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3ecbf/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite this using joins, MySQL has known issues with subqueries, especially when dealing with large data sets:

```
SELECT  n.*, 
        `id` as `newscode`, 
        COALESCE(l.TotalLikes, 0) AS `total_likes`,
        COALESCE(c.TotalComments, 0) AS `total_comments`
FROM    `news` n
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Code, COUNT(*) AS TotalLikes
            FROM    `likes` 
            WHERE   `type` = "newspost" 
            GROUP BY Code
        ) AS l
            ON l.`code` = n.`id`
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  post_id, COUNT(*) AS TotalComments
            FROM    `news_comments` 
            GROUP BY post_id
        ) AS c
            ON c.`post_id` = n.`id`
ORDER BY n.`id` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The reason is that when you use a join as above, MySQL will materialise the results of the subquery when it is first needed, e.g at the start of this query, mySQL will put the results of:

```
SELECT  post_id, COUNT(*) AS TotalComments
FROM    `news_comments` 
GROUP BY post_id
```

into an in memory table and hash post_id for faster lookups. Then for each row in `news` it only has to look up `TotalComments` from this hashed table, when you use a correlated subquery it will execute the query once for each row in `news`, which when `news` is large will result in a large number of executions. If the initial result set is small you may not see a performance benefit and it may be worse.

**Examples on SQL Fiddle**

Finally, you may want to index the relevant fields in `news_comments` and `likes`. For this particular query I think the following indexes will help:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Likes_Code_Type ON Likes (Code, Type);
CREATE INDEX IX_newcomments_post_id ON news_comments (post_id);
```

Although you may need to split the first index into two:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Likes_Code ON Likes (Code);
CREATE INDEX IX_Likes_Type ON Likes (Type);
```

Comment: Im getting the error `Unknown column 'n.newscode' in 'on clause'` when running this.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? There separate tables.

Comment: In your subquery that gets `total_likes`, you have this in the WHERE clause: `\`code\`=\`newscode\``. What does `newscode` refer to here? I know they are separate tables, but presumably they are linked? Otherwise you are just getting the total number of likes, which will be the same for every row unless there is a relation.

Comment: newscode is the id of the current news post its using. It looks up the likes/comments by id. Newcode is a dynamically generated column for each result. AS show in the original query.

Comment: I have substituted in `N.\`id\`` for each instance of `newscode` at the query now runs.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with the query offered here vs denormalized columns.  Reason- when it gets to the join, it has to do the full query of counts for ALL Codes and types before the JOIN is applied.  If the user only wants 5 IDs, and it grows to a million+ records, your query will not perform as you hope it would.

Comment: @DRapp I have reworded slightly, changing things like "should" to "could". I appreciate your point, however I also think that I explained your point in the answer, stating that the materialisation of derived tables was a performance benefit with a larger source. Although I did not explicitly state the inverse, I assumed it was a given, I have also added this in.

Comment: It is also a very large leap to say that demormalised columns is going to be a benefit, it the above query is only run on one or pages, but there are thousands of likes/comments a day then the cost of maintaining the demormalised columns will far out way the cost of a few queries. So you can only really *strongly* disagree based on an assumption about the OP's environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a `total_likes` and `total_comments` fields to the `news` table which gets incremented/decremented whenever a like and/or comment is added or removed.

Your `likes` and `news_comments` tables should be used for historical purposes only.

This strenuous counting should not be performed every time a page is loaded because that is a complete waste of resources.

Comment: @user3205106, Where I was going too, but it should be on an INSERT trigger into the likes / comments tables.  This is a common issue, especially for web to DENORMALIZE for counts that would otherwise bring queries to a crawl.

Comment: Thank you @DRapp I assume you simply forgot to mention it should be upon DELETE as well as INSERT because generally speaking users can usually perform both a Like and Un-Like operation unless OP was to lock them into their decision upon liking something. The same rule can apply to comments as well considering the fact that comments are likely to be moderated. Hence the increment/decrement portion of my answer.

Comment: correct, it should be on insert, update and delete, but the triggers would still be the better consideration for denormalization of totals.

Answer (score 0):

First check for helping indexes on columns **id**, **post_id** and **type,code**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is T-SQL, as that is what I am most familiar with.

First I would check indexes. If that looks good, then I'd check statement. Take a look at your query map to see how it's populating your result.

SQL works backward, so it starts with your last `AND` statement and goes from there. It'll group them all by code, and then type, and finally give you a count.

Right now, you're grabbing everything with certain codes, regardless of date. When you stated that you want the latest, I assume there is a date column somewhere.

In order to speed things up, add another `AND` to your `WHERE` and account for the date. Either last 24 hours, last week, whatever.

Comment: The assumption the question relates to T-SQL is franked by the fact that the question is tagged with `MySQL`. The statement  that SQL works backwards so starts with the last AND statement it not true at all, it starts with the table you are selecting from, then deals with any joins (in whatever order it deems fit unless you say otherwise), and then deals with your where clause, again in any order that the optimiser deems fastest.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check the tags. Obviously, SQL starts with table aggregation `FROM`, but after that, data absolutely is parsed 'backward': `WHERE`, `GROUP`, `HAVING`, `SELECT`, `ORDER BY`. My suggestion was to refine the `WHERE` clause as, after the table and joins are processed, that's the next step.